Can anyone explain me why at executing Console.WriteLine(foo) variable value doesn't increases?
I know it seems pretty easy but idk why I can't understand it.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
    object bar = foo;
    object qux = foo;
    object baz = bar;
    Console.WriteLine(baz);
    Console.WriteLine(bar);
    Console.WriteLine(baz);
    Console.WriteLine(qux);
}
struct Foo
{
    public int value;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        value++;
        return $"{value}";
    }
}

This code output this: 1 1 1 2 3 1.

Okay, I just realised it by myself

The point is, C# doesn't use our overridden ToString() method in Console.WriteLine(foo); so value into the foo variable do not increases, but if I write  Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString());, value will increase.

C# does use the overridden ToString method in Console.WriteLine, that's why you see 1 instead the default 0. It will not increase to 2 because structs are passed by value.
